# How/where should I initialize stuff such as database creation, loading resources from APIs etc. upon application start?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am currently creating an Android application using Android Studio and I have a question or two regarding what the most appropriate way of initializing "stuff" is.

As of right now I do the initializing in the `onCreate` method of the `MainActivity` which also serves as the "main"/"launcher" activity.

The initializing consists of

- creating a room-database that will be used later on

  - Regarding the creating/fetching of the database, seemingly the written code below works to get the instance object even after the database has already been created once. This leaves me to think that perhaps I shouldn't be building another one with the same name but instead fetch it from somewhere? At the same time seemingly the `databaseBuilder()` seems to be returning the existing instance if it exists... so the code works anyway but is it appropriate?
- setting the theme mode to light or dark depending on the user's phone mode
- initializing resources from an Android Studio library/API that I am using.

I have a feeling initializing things in this way and in this place (onCreate in MainActivity) is inappropriate and it can (should?) be done elsewhere and in some other way. So my question is **How/where should I be doing the initializing of stuff like this?**

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
// ...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //applicationContext.deleteDatabase("database-name")

        // Create the database
        val achievementDao = Room.databaseBuilder(
                applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,"database-name"
            ).build().achievementDao()

        // Just some random "test" code
        GlobalScope.launch {
            achievementDao.insertAll(Achievement("title1", "desc1", "date1", "false"))
            achievementDao.insertAll(Achievement("title2", "desc2", "date2", "true"))
            Log.i("database", achievementDao.getAll().toString())
            Log.i("database", achievementDao.getAllComplete().toString())
            Log.i("database", achievementDao.getAllIncomplete().toString())
        }

        // Set relevant theme depending on phone's mode (LIGHT or DARK)
        val currentNightMode = (resources.configuration.uiMode
                and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK)
        when (currentNightMode) {
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
                // Night mode is not active
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            }
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                // Night mode is active
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            }
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED -> { }
        }

        // Load in resources
        World.init(applicationContext)

        // ...

}
// ...
```

Comment: Why don't you try to do those tasks in the `Application` class?

Comment: @Sambhav.K Well, I have no idea what that is. I will have to Google it and see what it is about. Feel free to inform me of what the usefulness of this so called `Application` class is.

Comment: A custom application class is the class which `extends Application`. It is the first class that gets initialised when the app is opened. Refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) for more info on it

Comment: @Sambhav.K Thanks, I will look into it.  Post an actual answer to the question and I might eventually accept it.

Comment: Pls look into my answer

Answer (score 1):

**I'd prefer you to do this task in the custom `Application` class.** This is how you can create it:

1. Create a new class named `MyApplication.kt` or anything you want.
2. Make it to extend `Application`
3. There, in the `onCreate()` method, you can do all the tasks for your initialisation.
4. You must pass that class in the manifest like this:

   ```xml
   <application>
      android:name=".MyApplication"
      ...
   </application>
   ```

To know more about Application class, refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) site.

Answer (score 0):

> Regarding the creating/fetching of the database, seemingly the written code below works to get the instance object even after the database has already been created once. This leaves me to think that perhaps I shouldn't be building another one with the same name but instead fetch it from somewhere? At the same time seemingly the databaseBuilder() seems to be returning the existing instance if it exists... so the code works anyway but is it appropriate?

When you build the database, it doesn't in fact create the database. It builds an instance that will open or create the database when it is accessed (typically via a Dao, but can be done otherwise).

So in your case the database is only created when `achievementDao.insertAll(Achievement("title1", "desc1", "date1", "false"))` runs.

Without going in too deep. The `@Database` annotated class instance will see if the database (the file named *database-name*) exists (at location *data/data/databases/database-name*). If the file does not exist then the database (and therefore the file) will be created. If it exists, then it will be accessed/opened via the underlying SQLite API.

As such it doesn't really matter where you access the database, application or the first activity (reading further and implemnting the onCreate Callback, it simple does not matter where at all).

**However**, you do need to be careful in that you don't inadvertently keep adding the data whenever the App is run, or that you handle conflicts (e.g. a unique constraint can be ignored via the `onConflict =` parameter of an `@Insert`).

What you may well wish to consider, is using the `onCreate` callback. This will only run once for the lifetime of the database (as it says when the database is first created), thus the data added is added once and only the once (no resource wasteful attempts to add data only for it to be ignored etc), the drawback is that you can't use the Dao's (they will not have been fully instantiated at this stage). Rather you need to use the [SupportSQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase) passed to the `onCreate` method of the callback, and the methods available to it such as execSQL, insert etc.

see https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback

Another option is to utilise a pre-packaged database, where the database, with some data is placed into the assets folder (doesn't have to have data but without it's a bit of a waste). Here you would use the `.createFromAsset` method/function added to the invocation of the `databaseBuilder`. This is preferable if there is a large amount of data, rather than bulking up the code